# Containerd: Copying files from containerd container to host

Tags: docker, containerd

I am looking for equivalent of `docker cp` command in containerd.

For example what will be the equivalent of below in containerd

```
docker cp <container-id>:<path> <host-path>
```

```
ex: docker cp ed128ed:/etc/file1 file1
```

Answer (score -1):

There are no features same as `docker cp` on containerd, but you can use the command `ctr snapshot mounts` which mounts the container's root to the host path.

```
mkdir /tmp/containerfiles
ctr snapshot mounts /tmp/containerfiles {container_id}
```

Then you can copy any contents of the container from `/tmp/containerfiles`.

Comment: I could not find any files inside /tmp/containerfiles after mounting

Answer (score -1):

recommend
`kubectl cp`

```
kubectl cp  -n <namespace> <pod-name>:<path>  <destination>
```

as an example :

```
kubectl cp -n ix-onlyoffice onlyoffice-ix-chart-6d8bb6698-zpg46:var/www/onlyoffice/documentserver/core-fonts ./core-fonts
```

if there is no kubectl ;
I cant find a good way to do that.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).